# Problems changing the gamma tables in the monitor using CGGetDisplayTransferByTable

Tags: macos, core-graphics, retina-display

**tldr**: There are some monitor luminance interpolation/resetting in the monitors that are not controlled by the CoreGraphics framework, and I can't figure out what it is.

---

I have a macbook pro retina display (2012). I am using the CGGetDisplayTransferByTable function (CoreGraphics framework) to change the gammaTables of the monitor. I am feeding in 3 x 1024 element arrays taken from 0 to 1, with the same array for red, green and blue table.

When I display all the 1024 values on the monitor in a line, it seems to be cutting off ~50 of the first values and the ~10 of the last values. That is, changing the first 50 values of the gamma table to 1 does not change the colors on any part of the monitor.

In addition, when I zoom in on the first values, they seem to be unstable and keep changing luminance values based on some interpolation algorithm.

Does anybody have an idea why this might be changing? Are there any other processes in macOS that may be overwriting the changes that I am making to the gamma table? (i've disabled night shift, flux, and other apps that)

For instance, I am using the following code:

```
int numTableEntries = CGDisplayGammaTableCapacity(CGMainDisplayID())

CGGammaValue redTable[] = {1,1,1,1,1,1,1, ..., 0,1/245, etc.., ......., 1}; // numTableEntries values here 
CGGammaValue greenTable[] = {1,1,1,1,1,1,1, ..., 0,1/246, ......., 1}; // numTableEntries values here 
CGGammaValue blueTable[] = {1,1,1,1,1,1,1,..., 0,1/246, ......., 1}; // numTableEntries values here 

CGSetDisplayTransferByTable(CGMainDisplayID(), numTableEntries, redTable, greenTable, blueTable);
```

This should be changing the darkest pixels to white. Instead, I still see dark parts on the screen.

---

**Update:**
I've tested the same thing on a Mac Pro 2013 with Dell monitors.

CGSetDisplayTransferByTable seems to be doing something weird here too. When I set all the table values to a single value, it doesn't change the screen at all (while it should be blanking out the screen).

```
CGGammaValue oneTable[] = {0.5, 0.5}; // numTableEntries values here 
CGSetDisplayTransferByTable(CGMainDisplayID(), sizeof(oneTable)/sizeof(oneTable[0]), oneTable, oneTable, oneTable);
```

I imagine there must be something weird going on behind the hood that checks the GammaTable coming in to the video card...

Comment: Edit your question to show the code you're using to change the gamma table. How did you pick 1024 as the size of your array?

Comment: @KenThomases sorry about the clarity. I hope it is more clear now!